# Running custom method of the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift3

```
class func loadData(
    onCompletition: @escaping ([LocationInfo])->Void){
    let workingQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos:.utility)
    let completitionQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    workingQueue.sync {
        print("\n Data fetch started \n")
        let root = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let locationSummary = root.child("LocSummary")

        locationSummary.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { (snapshot) in
            for item in snapshot.children{
                let locationInfo = LocationInfo(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                FirebaseDataController.resultsArray.append(locationInfo)
            }
            completitionQueue.async {
                print("\n data fetch completed \n ")

                onCompletition(FirebaseDataController.resultsArray)
                print("After on completion method")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The problem I have no is that, every time I want to access the data inside the results array I have to go through this functions completion handler.  Which is not something I can do all the time specially when I want to work with table views and such (I have a seperate class to handle all DB interactions and many other classes to handle table view interactions).

My objective is to run this code at the start of the application may be through the AppDelegate and have a populated array that I can call anytime I want access to data.

To do this I think I need to run this code on the main thread. I tried that by substituting the workingQueue with the main thread but the application keeps crashing.

Is there is anything that I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will crash only if you call this synchronously on main thread when launching application because you cause a deadlock. If you run this function in `application:didFinishLaunching:` method of AppDelegate you should be able to use safely this implementation:

```
class func loadData(onCompletition: @escaping ([LocationInfo])->Void){
    let completitionQueue = DispatchQueue.main   

    print("\n Data fetch started \n")
    let root = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let locationSummary = root.child("LocSummary")

    locationSummary.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children{
            let locationInfo = LocationInfo(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            FirebaseDataController.resultsArray.append(locationInfo)
        }
        completitionQueue.async {
            print("\n data fetch completed \n ")

            onCompletition(FirebaseDataController.resultsArray)
            print("After on completion method")
        }
    })
}
```

Your guess that you need to perform this operations on the main thread is wrong - there is no reason to do that, in fact, you will end up with stalled user interface. Fetch the data, and then asynchronously update user interface on main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've done what you said. I created a another method. To fetch the results array as follows. 

class func fetchData(){
        loadData { (data) in
            self.resultsArray = (data as NSArray) as! [LocationInfo]
            print("/n table view \(resultsArray.count) /n")
        }
    }

And I call this method from the app deligate. However,  now I need a way to reference my Table View controller and reload the data after it has be loaded to the results array. 

How can I reference the table view from loadData function or the fetch function?

Comment: Regarding reloading the table view, this is of course possible but - this is also different question - can you post another one and reference me in a comment? And accept this one if it solved primary issue. This is because StackOverflow is a question&answer platform, and try to avoid asking many questions in one. You can for example send NSNotification and set your relevant view controller as observer.

Comment: @MinonWeerasinghe and you should not pass 'self' to closure executed in the same class because this causes a retain cycle - use capture list, i will help you with that in another question, remember to post the code so most people will learn from your case:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to call the method on main thread.

- First thing you remove all the code related to `DispatchQueue`.
- Then call the `loadData` using `- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;`